# Duplicate (but slightly different) notification for yearling badge

Tags: support, notifications

I just noticed that the notification for the "Yearling" badge appears twice in slightly different incarnations.

[image: Yes, I heard you the first time]

Looking at past notifications, the same thing happened when I got the "Yearling" badge for SuperUser, but not for Area51.

Why is this happening?

Comment: @TimStone that address why the first instance looks different but does not mention a duplicate notifications.

Comment: They're technically different badges (although I don't know how the awarding criteria works for the one on the per-site meta), so that seems correct.

Comment: Ahh... ok. Makes sense.

Comment: That's not a dupe IMO, voting to reopen.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard want to try again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a meta yearling badge and a yearling badge for the main site.

This is what you're seeing, notice that the logos are slightly different (one color, the other monochrome)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if the notification made that clearer.

Comment: Not always. If you don't [visit ***and*** participate on the child meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339777/why-do-all-the-meta-stacksites-seem-to-require-an-account/339779#comment1135063_339779) it's not awarded on the meta (only the main).

Comment: @KeithThompson when in doubt, hover. The tooltip says which site the notification is from.