# Duplicate yearling achievement in notification

Tags: bug

[image]

Almost-duplicates:

- [Duplicate (but slightly different) notification for yearling badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149122/duplicate-but-slightly-different-notification-for-yearling-badge)
- [Why did I get yearling badge twice in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158054/why-did-i-get-yearling-badge-twice-in-a-day)

Comment: See the icons, one is gray meaning one is for the main site and one is for the child meta site.

Comment: Subtle, but I see it now.

Comment: Yeah, since the main site favicon got lots of gray already, it's hard to see. Can't blame you!